# Sorting of eigenvalues in Python in for-loop

Tags: python, sorting, numpy, matplotlib, linear-algebra

I am calculating and plotting the eigenvalues of a 5x5 array as a function of a parameter x. I know that I have to sort the eigenvalues since they are not necessarily ordered with numpy, so the easiest way is to use argsort() and sort them from smallest to largest (or vice versa):

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np

    #matrix values
    A=20
    B=8
    C=10
    D = 10
    E=30
    q1 = 6
    q2=5

    xx = np.linspace(0,30,300) 


    ev1=np.array([])
    ev2=np.array([])
    ev3=np.array([])
    ev4=np.array([])
    ev5=np.array([])
    for x in np.arange(0,30, 0.1):
      vals, vecs = (np.linalg.eig([[A,0,x,0,0],[0,B,q1,0,0][x,q1,C,0,0][q2,0,q2,D,0],[0,0,0,0,E]]))
      idx = vals.argsort()[::-1]   
      vals = vals[idx]
      vecs = vecs[:,idx]
      ev1=np.append(ev1, vals[0])
      ev2=np.append(ev2, vals[1])
      ev3=np.append(ev3, vals[2])
      ev4=np.append(ev4, vals[3])
      ev5=np.append(ev5, vals[4])

      plt.figure(figsize=(7.5,4.5))
      plt.plot(xx, ev1)
      plt.plot(xx, ev2)
      plt.plot(xx, ev3)
      plt.plot(xx, ev4)
      plt.plot(xx, ev5)
      plt.savefig('eigenvalues.jpg')
      plt.show()
```

However I am not very happy with the result (see attached plot) since this does not give the correct dependence of the eigenvalues, e.g. the horizontal line that is blue initially switches to orange but I would like it to stay blue, similarity for the red curve. However, I don't know how to implement this.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions!

[image: graph showing current results]

Comment: From your question, it seems like you only don't know how to set the color of the curve. Is that true?

Comment: No that was just to visualize my problem. My problem is deeper, I am looking for a way to sort the eigenvalues and associated eigenvectors in a continuous fashion.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're over-complicating your problem here. When you are using the argsort on the eigenvalues and appending, you're simply getting lists of the highest, second highest, lowest values, etc and are ignoring the eigenvector data. If you remove the whole argsort part of your code, the plotting code will work fine, since the eigenvalues are linked in position to the correct eigenvector.[image]